# My mock is not returning any data - Angularjs

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I am trying to create some basic test coverage of a service that I have created.  Here is my service:

```
App.factory('encounterService', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
  return {
    encounters: [],
    encountersTotalCount: 0,
    encountersIndex: 0,
    resource: $resource('/encounters/:encounterId', {encounterId:'@encounterId'}, {
      search: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'RemoteUser': 'jjjyyy',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    }),
    getMoreEncounters: function() {
      var that = this;
      that.resource.search({}, function(data) {
        that.encountersTotalCount = data.metadata.totalCount;
        _.each(data.encounters, function(encounter) {
          that.encounters.push(encounter);
        });
        that.busy = false;
        that.offset += 10;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('encountersFetched');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This is my test:

```
describe('encounterService', function() {
  var _encounterService, httpBackend;
  beforeEach(inject(function(encounterService, $httpBackend) {
    _encounterService = encounterService;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    var url = 'encounters';
    httpBackend.when('GET', url).respond([{}, {}, {}]);
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should return a list of encounters', function() {
    _encounterService.getMoreEncounters();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(_encounterService.encounters.size).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

My test is running and my service is calling `getMoreEncounters()`.  Inside the `encounterService` I am supposed to set some metadata and assign my data to an internal variable.  This never happens.  You can see the response in the test, but the results do not get assigned to anything . What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Does the `encounterService` work outside of your test?  Just by looking at this code, it doesn't look like it should work at all...

Comment: Really?  I see a couple of things that I believe should throw javascript errors.  `expect(_encounterService.encounters.size).toBe(3);` is one of them.  Javascript arrays don't have a `.size` property.  its `.length`...

Comment: My `encounterService` ran fine, but you did find my error.  It should be `.length` not `.size`.  I was getting 0 for a `size` property, because it didn't exist.  Make a proper answer and I will credit you.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above by `tennisgent`:

> I see a couple of things that I believe should throw javascript errors. `expect(_encounterService.encounters.size).toBe(3);` is one of them. Javascript arrays don't have a `.size` property. its `.length`.
>
> I was getting `0` for a `size` property, because it didn't exist.